# Passing an URL as a paramter using URL rewriting (apache)

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a .htaccess file in which I try to rewrite certain URL's. My goals is to pass an URL to another script as a parameter. It kind of works, but I end up with URL's that only contain one forward slash in the protocol part (e.g. http:/ instead of http://)

This is my .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

php_flag register_globals off
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_value display_errors 0

FileETag none
ServerSignature Off

Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ test.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC,NE,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now when I request the following : *http://example.org/test/http://myurl.com*, the php $_REQUEST object contains an url variable containing *http:/myurl.com*

EDIT When I request : *http://example.org/test/http%3A%2F%2Fmyurl.com*, the URL doesn't get rewritten at all (doesn't match the rewrite regex somehow)

I cannot seem to find the proper solution for this problem, it doesn't seem to be a problem with escape characters (since that would be a backslash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you shouldn't capture the URL from `RewriteRule` since Apache replaces all `//` by `/`.

Replace your rule with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+test/([^\s]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ test.php?url=%1 [QSA,NE,L]
</IfModule>
```

THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser.

Comment: Thanks, you've gotten me on the right track! I had to change a few things in your answer, but you have definitely pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: Could you change the '$1' backreference to '%1' and the RewriteRule line should start with ^.*$ Then I can accept your submission as an answer.

Comment: @QNimbus Sorry I meant `%1` and by mistake typed `$1` corrected now.

Comment: About `RewriteRule ^` it is same as `RewriteRule ^.*$` (and probably faster since it doesn't match full URI again.

Comment: @ anubhava You're right about `RewriteRule ^`, I didn't know that! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in a URL the slash is considered a directory. Resolving `path//file` you get `path/file`. That's what happens in your case.

To properly encode it, you must replace the slashes of the `http://myurl.com` with `%2F`: `http:%2F%2Fmyurl.com`. See [`percent encoding`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encodinghttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for more information.

A simpler workaround would be to ditch `http://` in general.

Comment: I understand your point, however when I escape (urlencode) the url that I want to pass, the rewrite regex doesn't match anymore somehow.